# Is there a way to get the variable type?

Tags: stata

I would like to pull out the categorical variables in Stata but it seems I am not doing the right thing. Any leads?

```
* Pull out variables with value labels 

sysuse auto
label dir 

local catvars = r(names)

foreach var of varlist _all{
    if `var' in `catvars'{
        di "`var'"
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives you a list of the names of value labels (one name for each set). It will give the right answer if and only if variables with value labels each have value labels with the same name as the variable, which is true of some datasets, but is in no sense compulsory. In this case the variable `foreign` has the value label `origin`, so the code fails completely to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the criterion for a categorical variable is that it has value labels, then `ds` is the simplest tool:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. ds, has(vallabel)
foreign
```

`ds` returns a list of such variables (here just one) in `r(varlist)`.

`ds` is an official command. The specific syntax just used, the option `has()`, was my addition in a community-contributed command later folded back into what is distributed with Stata itself (which is what "official" means here).

`findname` from the *Stata Journal* has the same functionality, and  much more. It was written by me as an extension of `ds`. In some cases. as for this problem, the syntax is different, representing my second thoughts on what is clean, but users naturally may disagree.

```
. findname, vallabel
foreign
```

THe general question in the title can be answered too. `help macro` is the gateway to documentation of various low-level tools, which in essence underline most of what  `ds` and `findname` do as a matter of convenience. `findname` now also uses some Mata functionality that isn't directly matched in Stata itself. Among the extra options of `findname` is `local()` to put the results of `findname` directly into a local macro; there is no such option in `ds`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick how about if I want to apply function to each categorical variable in Stata in say a forloop?

Comment: The main technique is one you already know, to copy the names to a `local` macro and then loop over that list.